# Apache mod_rewrite - rewrite to folder name based on %{HTTP_HOST} - infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I'm currently stuck with an infinite loop problem with mod_rewrite.

What I want (rules to be applied in order):

- stript www (redirect)
- rewrite request so that the files within the folder named %{HTTP_HOST} (if existent) are used
- if the folder doesn't exist, redirect to domain.tld

Examples:

- www.subdomain.domain.tld => redirect to subdomain.domain.tld
- subdomain.domain.tld => load files within folder named subdomain.domain.tld (and pass the rest of the request)
- unknown-subdomain.domain.tld => redirect to domain.tld

What I got so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Store protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) as ENV variable
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"https"' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]

# Stript www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:proto}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA,R=301]

# Directory exists => rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%{HTTP_HOST} [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} -d
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]

# Directory doesn't exist => redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%{HTTP_HOST} [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !-d
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:proto}://domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA,R]
```

I know all this can be achieved with virtual hosts. Unfortunately, I'm already on a shared virtual host and .htaccess is all I can make use of, so I'm kinda forced to go that way.

I'm thankful for any help or ideas to lead me to the right direction.

Comment: Where are you looking for the directories? Also, if all your subdomains support HTTPS, always redirect your users to a SSL connection.

Comment: The directories are in the same folder as the .htaccess. The preservation of the protocol is more of a gimmick and because it's unsupported in the development environment. You're absolutely right to always use HTTPS, if possible, which will be the case in the final version.

Comment: What is the apache version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]

# Strip www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:proto}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA,R=301]

#Prevent loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Directory exists => rewrite
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST} -d
RewriteRule ^ /%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]

# Directory doesn't exist => redirect (but not if host=example.com)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:proto}://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA,R]
```